# jQuery UI Sortable - ConnectToSortable issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to create a drag & drop interface for icons. Basically, I have three div containers, each one with an ordered list inside. The first list holds the icons (as `<li><img /></li>`), and the two remaining ones are empty and should receive icons being dragged, dropped, and sorted inside of them. Each empty list is associated to a row where the icons will be displayed in the front end.

I have also created a function to allow item selection on Ctrl/Cmd + Left Mouse Click, so that users can drop multiple icons at a time.

Everything works as expected, except for one single issue: the custom Ctrl/Cmd + Click option stops working on draggable elements that have already been dropped.

After realizing, I did some testing and narrowed it down as much as possible: it seems that the culprit is the ConnectToSortable parameter in the 'Draggable' function. If the parameter is commented out, the Ctrl+Click function works as expected. The problem is that I need to use this parameter in order to store all the icons associated to each empty list (row) so I can retrieve them later.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="row1" class="row">
    <ol class="drop-container">
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares blue-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares blue-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares blue-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="row2" class="row">
    <ol class="drop-container">
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares red-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares red-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares red-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="row3" class="row">
    <ol class="drop-container">
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares green-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares green-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li class='draggable'><span class="squares green-squares">&nbsp;</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

​

And Here is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
// Custom function for Ctrl-Cmd Left Mouse Click
$(".draggable, .ui-draggable").click(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey === true) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
    }
});
// Draggable
$('.draggable').draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".drop-container",
    delay: 200,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    },
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 300
});
// Droppable
$('.drop-container').droppable({
    tolerance: "touch"
});
// Sortable
$('.drop-container').sortable({
    appendTo: ".drop-container",
    connectWith: ".drop-container",
    items: ".draggable",
    revert: true
});
// Disable selection of items
$("div, ol, ul, li, span").disableSelection();
});​
```

I made a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SWJ7D/81/) to test this, and I was able to reproduce the error. I am using spans instead of actual images for the purposes of this test.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a jQuery UI bug? Any ideas or workarounds are most welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$('.drop-container').sortable("refresh");
```

once the items are dropped in.  See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. I added a function on "drop" event and it doesn't seem to make any difference as far as the Ctrl+Left click selection goes: once the item is dropped, it becomes unselectable. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SWJ7D/86/) is the updated JSfiddle.

Comment: there is some kind of error on drag: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0; 97890703; update/02115)
Timestamp: Wed, 21 Mar 2012 18:04:21 UTC


Message: 'data(...).options' is null or not an object
Line: 1402
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Hi, Marcus, thanks for getting back to me. I'll look into that error and try to see if the issue is generated by my code or if it happens every single time dragging occurs.